# Show that an operation of elements in a finite group contains each element exactly once

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Finite group $G$ contains elements $g_1,g_2,...,g_n$. Show that $g_1g,g_2g,...,g_ng$ consists of every element from $G$, where $g\in G$.

I know that the operation of a finite group gives back each element of the group once, but how can I prove this? I know I have to show that some $g_ig$ is in the group and some $g_ig$ does not equal some $g_jg$

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE! Do you want to show that $\forall h \in G, \exists! g\in G$ such that $h=g_1 g,\dots,g_n g$?

Comment: Yes that what I want to show

Comment: Please do not repeat the same question again, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2958332/abstract-algebra-show-that-if-the-finite-group-g-comprises-the-elements).

Answer (score 1):

Fix the $g \in G$. Define $f : G \to G$ by $f(x) = xg$. Let us show that it is injective. Suppose $f(x) = f(y)$. Then $xg = yg$. But then $xgg^{-1} = ygg^{-1} \implies x = y$, so $f$ is indeed injective. Because $G$ is a finite set, any map $G \to G$ which is injective is actually bijective, so $f$ is bijective.

So for any $y \in G$, there exists a unique $g_i \in G$ such that $f(g_i) = g_ig = y$. This is exactly what you wanted to show.

Comment: How can I show that each element appears exactly once under the operation?

Comment: Thanks, sorry I understand now. You showed gi is unique element